Flutter - navigation to particular screen form notification (local or push from firebase) with in app lock screen
I am working on an app which has a lock screen and requires local auth when app reopens or it is timed out. But I am trying to implement a navigation where user taps on notification and app opens up and after the local auth it is redirected to that particular screen otherwise the local auth takes the user to dashboard.
If the app is in running mode and it gets locked and users taps on notification A1, after local auth it redirected to the particular screen A1, But if the app is closed from the background and user taps the notification A1 then it does not go to that screen A1.
any ideas or already implemented solutions for this?
 static Future<void> _handleNavigation(Map<String, dynamic> data) async {
    if (data.containsKey('type')) {
      Widget screen;

      if (data['type'] == 'contract_1' && data.containsKey('contractId')) {
        String contractId = data['contractId'];
        screen = ContractDetailScreen(contractId: contractId);
      } else if (data['type'] == 'contract_2' && data.containsKey('contractId')) {
        String contractId = data['contractId'];
        screen = SelfContractDetailScreen(contractId: contractId);
      } else if (data['type'] == 'contract_3' && data.containsKey('contractId')) {
        String contractId = data['contractId'];
        screen = SoloContractDetailScreen(contractId: contractId);
      } else {
        // Handle unexpected types or missing contractId
        return;
      }

      await _navigateToScreen(screen);
    }
  }

  static Future<bool> _checkIfAppIsLocked() async {
    // Assuming `auth.checkUserInactive()` is an asynchronous method that returns Future<bool>
    return await auth.checkUserInactive();
  }

  static Future<void> _navigateToScreen(Widget screen) async {
    bool isAppLocked = await _checkIfAppIsLocked();
    print("App locked: $isAppLocked");

